# When I tried to push my newly created files into GitHub repo, I get the following error, Why this error occurs?

Tags: github

I can't get why this error occurs, please help.
Previously I had pushed many files into my gitHub repository. Only this time error occurs.

```
 ! [rejected] gh-pages -> gh-pages (fetch first)
    error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/Subhra-commits/Coursera_Course.git'
    hint: Updates were rejected because the remote contains work that you do
    hint: not have locally. This is usually caused by another repository pushing
    hint: to the same ref. You may want to first integrate the remote changes
    hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
    hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Comment: You should pull remote changes from github, before pushing, as the git error message says "You may want to first integrate the remote changes
    hint: (e.g., 'git pull ...') before pushing again."
Run git pull, merge changes and push it to github again.

Comment: @MikhailSidorov 

the "git pull" request gives another following error also:

**C:\Users\SBC\Coursera_Course\Coursera_Course>git pull**

`error: Pulling is not possible because you have unmerged files.`
`hint: Fix them up in the work tree, and then use 'git add/rm <file>'`
`hint: as appropriate to mark resolution and make a commit.`
`fatal: Exiting because of an unresolved conflict.`

Comment: @MikhailSidorov can you provide detail steps by step guides to resolve this.

Comment: You should read about git merge because it is the base command of git. Unfortunately, I cannot provide step-by-step instructions on how to do merge. You can read about the merge process here https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge. Also, you can use the git status command, to see files with merge conflicts. Then you should check all files with conflicts and resolve them. Hope I was able to help.

Comment: @MikhailSidorov thank you for your help. I had successfully fixed my problem then.